# Is it possible to automatic naming in R?

Tags: r, naming

I want an automatic naming in my function. For example I import a data by 'sample' name. To do this I tried a function like that.

`fnctn<-function(a) {data(names(a))}`

But when I write `fnctn(sample)`; I got this

```
Warning message:
In data(names(a)) : data set ‘names(a)’ not found
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you be more specific? What do you want to to do with this function? I would suggest , `fnctn<-function(a) {data(get(a))}`, `a` being of type character. So `fnctn("sample")`

Comment: Thank you @DJJ .  I have codes progressing like that. 
data(HistDailyData)
write.table(HistDailyData,file="HistDailyData.txt",sep="\t",
quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE) 
In this, HistDailyData will be my data. And I will always add new data. So I created a function by 'trial' name. My aim is, when I add a new data I want to this HistDailyData part to be changed automatically. For example; my first data is 'january'. I'll write trial(january) and I ll get data(january) and write.table(january,file="january.txt",sep="\t",
quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)